# Service in Manifest.xml when uncomented causes app to not be able to install

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I'm having an issues with adding a service tag to my manifest file.  The app compiles fine but when it goes to actually install on my device it just errors out and fails to install due to a manifest issues.  Android Studio then stops recognizing some of my activities.  If I comment out the service as seen in the code sample below the app will install just fine, of course though I can't use my service now.

So what am I doing wrong with my service tag?

For reference the complete source for the app can be found here
https://github.com/Jazzeroki/LacunaExpress

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
package="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="0.10" >

<!-- SDK Levels -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<!-- Application Declarations -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <!-- This is the Splash Screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- This is the Add Account Activity -->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.AddAccount"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <!-- This is the Add Select Account Activity for selecting the login account-->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.SelectAccount"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <!-- This is the Add Account Manager Activity -->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.AccountMan"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>


    <!-- This is the Add Account Info Activity -->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.AccountInfo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>


    <!-- This is the Modify Account Info Activity -->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.ModifyAccount"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>     

    <!-- This is the Accounts Activity -->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.Accounts"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>


    <!-- This is the User Settings Activity -->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.UserSettingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <!-- This is the Select Message2 Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.SelectMessageActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <!-- This is the compose message activity -->
    <activity 
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.ComposeMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.ReadMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <!--
    <service android:name="Server.ServerIntentService"/> -->



<!-- End Application -->
</application>
```

Comment: where is the manifest tag?

Comment: Why don't you use package name in service name?

Comment: pass fully qualified name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move package

```
Server\
```

into

```
app\src\main\java\com\JazzDevStudio\LacunaExpress\
```

After, you'll able add it at `manifest` as

```
<service android:name=".Server.ServerIntentService"/>
```

OR

```
<service android:name="com.JazzDevStudio.LacunaExpress.Server.ServerIntentService"/>
```

Please put in order names of your packages, from [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

> Naming Conventions
>
> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the
>   names of classes or interfaces.
>
> Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their
>   package names—for example, com.example.mypackage for a package named
>   mypackage created by a programmer at example.com.
>
> Name collisions that occur within a single company need to be handled
>   by convention within that company, perhaps by including the region or
>   the project name after the company name (for example,
>   com.example.region.mypackage).
>
> Packages in the Java language itself begin with java. or javax.
>
> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other
>   special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other
>   character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or
>   if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int".
>   In this event, the suggested convention is to add an underscore.

Comment: Thank you it was rather odd though that Android Studio only suggested the name that is in the service rather than the fqdn